# Forcing a ListBox to Update

Tags: c++, user-interface, listbox

I am using C++ with MFC, and I have a ListBox tied to a variable that I'm updating as I run through a function:

```
void CFileSelection::OnBnClickedFiletousb()
{

m_LogC.AddString(_T("Starting move to USB, Please Wait..."));
UpdateData(FALSE);

// Code to move files from disk to USB

m_LogC.AddString(_T("Move to USB Successful."));

}
```

However, despite the UpdateData, the ListBox doesn't populate with either string until it has completed it's task. Is there a way to make it update the screen before the rest of the code is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function after changing the text on the listbox. Your issue is that the other calls are blocking the MessageThread, but you can force an update with this.

```
void ProcessWindowMessages()
{
    MSG msg;

    while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))  // let them see the message before we go into longer term wait
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);                         // translate it
        DispatchMessage(&msg);                          // and let windows dispatch it to WinProc
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also call

```
yourlistboxVariable->UpdateWindow();
```